# How do you change prepared spells during long rest on the journey?

Tags: solasta-crown-of-magister

Since *Solasta :Crown of Magister* follows the rules of DnD 5e, your spellcasters can only change prepared spells during long rest (either around a camp fire on in the inn). When you are travelling, you have to go through a few long rests that restore your spells (if you have used them in combat), but I can nowhere see a way to swap spells, as the whole journey (and rests) takes place on the world map.

Can you change your prepared spells? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change them in the long rest interface, which appears when you rest at any long rest spot on a normal map or at an inn. During travel this screen is usually skipped.

Comment: So basically, does t mean that **you can't** change them during the journey, unless you've been attacked?

Comment: I noticed yesterday, you can't change them during the journey at all, as continue resting just finishes the rest. You need to manually rest at a rest spot in a dungeon or at an inn in order to change prepared spells.

Comment: @Yasskier In the difficulty settings you can change this particular setting; if you check the 'custom difficulty settings' box, then there is an entry for 'require a long rest to change prepared spells' that you can check/uncheck. I don't know what preset setting allows changing the without a long rest, but I know the 'standard' difficulty (and, presumably, the harder ones, too) has the box for 'require long rest' checked.

Comment: @TylerH that would be a decent answer

Comment: @Yasskier It doesn't answer the question you asked (and I haven't played a campaign where that checkbox is unchecked to know how one *would* change prepared spells outside of a long rest, which *would* answer the question).

Answer (score 2):

If you change the travel settings to "Interrupt after a long break", it will open the options of long break before continuing